# Does it matter which operand of integer division is static_casted to obtain a float result?

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-optimization

To obtain a float result from division of two `int`s, we `static_cast` one of the operands to `float`, like so:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
float c = static_cast<float>(a) / b;  // c = 0.666666
float d = a / static_cast<float>(b);  // d = 0.666666
```

In the above case, it shouldn't matter which operand is `static_cast`ed. However, suppose one of the operands is a compile-time constant, while the other is not, like so:

```
int a = foo();  // value not available at compile-time.
const int b = SOME_CONSTANT;  // compile-time constant.
```

Does compiler optimization make any difference to the two `static_cast`s, as described below?

```
float c = static_cast<float>(a) / b;
```

In this case, compiler can replace `b` with its value, but since `a` isn't known, the cast can happen only at runtime.

```
float d = a / static_cast<float>(b);
```

However, in this case, compiler knows `b`, so it could do the casting at compile-time, and replace `b` directly with the `float` value.

In both cases, after the casting, an integer/float (or float/integer) division happens at runtime.

Is this intuition correct, or can compilers be smart enough to optimize equally well in both cases? Are there any other factors I have overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `int/float` or `float/int` divisions happen at runtime. Ever.

Since one operand is being cast - explicitly converted - to `float`, the other will be implicitly converted to `float` for the division.

Both your cases are equivalent to

```
static_cast<float>(a) / static_cast<float>(b);
```